# Can't update image in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm beginner to ASP.NET Core, I am trying to update an image in a database,  I have some doubts about my code, image added to database but cannot update

**AdminController**

```
public async Task<ViewResult> Edit(int productId)
        {
            return View(await _repository.Products
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.ProductID == productId));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(Product product, IFormFile image)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if(image != null && image.Length > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(image.FileName);
                    var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot\\images\\items", fileName);
                    using(var fileSteam = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await image.CopyToAsync(fileSteam);
                    }
                    product.Image = fileName;
                }
                _repository.SaveProduct(product);
                TempData["message"] = $"{product.Name} has been edit";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return View(product);
            }
        }
```

**Edit.cshtml**

```
<form asp-action="Edit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="hidden" asp-for="ProductID" />

    <div class="form-group">
         <h4><label asp-for="Image"></label></h4>
         <input asp-for="Image" type="file" class="form-control" />
    </div>
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: My application can add an image and delete it in the database, but can't update. I do not know why

Comment: What do you mean not updated? It seems that you save file name in database and save files in `wwwroot` folder,does `Image` column not be replaced with new filename?

Comment: I try you code and it updates successfully.Since you do not post your respository code ,I use `_context.Update(product);await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` directly and it works.Make sure the `product.ProductID` is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm found where I was wrong, thanks Xing Zou! I updated the  `SaveProduct(product)`

```
public Product SaveProduct(Product productDataUpdate)
        {
            var prod = _context.Products.Attach(productDataUpdate);
            prod.State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified;
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return productDataUpdate;
        }
```